# Drawing Rectagles On Excel, Entire Row, "Run-time error :'1004'"

Tags: excel, runtime-error, ms-office, shapes, vba

I simplified my code:

I want to draw two Rectangles:
The First to Left Side of The Selected Cell (the code is not intented for First "A" Column)
The Second to Right Side Of Selected Cell (the code is not intented for Last "XFD" Column).

Function to be used by both code.

```
    Private Function NumToCol(numCol)
        NumToCol = Split(Cells(, numCol).Address, "$")(1)
    End Function
```

Here my code:

```
    Sub CreateLateralRectangles()
        'Working no problem

        Dim LftRctl As Shape
        Dim RhtRctl As Shape
        Dim RngRht As Range
        Dim RngLft As Range

        MyRow = ActiveCell.Row
        MyCol = ActiveCell.Column

        LftCol = MyCol - 1
        RgtCol = MyCol + 1

        LRng = NumToCol(LftCol - 3) & MyRow & ":" & NumToCol(LftCol) & MyRow
        RRng = NumToCol(RgtCol) & MyRow & ":" & NumToCol(RgtCol + 3) & MyRow

        Set RngRht = Range(RRng)
        Set RngLft = Range(LRng)

        MsgBox "Beging To Create"
        Set LftRctl = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, RngLft.Left, RngLft.Top, RngLft.Width, RngLft.Height)
        Set RhtRctl = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, RngRht.Left, RngRht.Top, RngRht.Width, RngRht.Height)
    End Sub
```

The next code presents "Run-time error :'1004'"  "Application-defined or object-defined error"

```
    Sub CreateFullRectangles()
        'Has problem

        Dim LftRctl As Shape
        Dim RhtRctl As Shape
        Dim RngRht As Range
        Dim RngLft As Range

        MyRow = ActiveCell.Row
        MyCol = ActiveCell.Column

        LftCol = MyCol - 1
        RgtCol = MyCol + 1

        LRng = "A" & MyRow & ":" & NumToCol(LftCol) & MyRow
        RRng = NumToCol(RgtCol) & MyRow & ":" & "XFD" & MyRow

        Set RngRht = Range(RRng)
        Set RngLft = Range(LRng)

        MsgBox "Beging To Create"
        Set LftRctl = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, RngLft.Left, RngLft.Top, RngLft.Width, RngLft.Height)
        Set RhtRctl = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, RngRht.Left, RngRht.Top, RngRht.Width, RngRht.Height)
    End Sub
```

But I can't figure out what's is the real error On second code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RRng` is too large. `RngRht.Width` equals to 785712. Try to reduce it by reducing the range. I changed XFD to FD to reduce it. You may change it as per your code need.

```
RRng = NumToCol(RgtCol) & MyRow & ":" & "FD" & MyRow
```

Comment: Max value for RRng, possible in excel on my machine is "EFA" i.e. RngRht.Width = 169056. As per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff700514%28v=office.14%29.aspx, Max allowed column is 16,384.